# PHP Patterns - how can I write this code?

Tags: php

I want to make an category-system CMS. Everything is fine, except a big trouble.

How can I can handle and generate the mysql query depends by some inputs like:

> site.com/some-category&sortby=views&from=smt&anotherInput=key

For example, for this input my query should be something like

```
SELECT * FROM `articles` WHERE from='smt' AND afield='key' ORDER BY VIEWS
```

But these inputs will be different. How I can write this code? I don't know much things about designs patterns, but, I've heard about Factory pattern, is this a part of my solution?

Than

Comment: This is basic PHP form handling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Factory pattern can help you with e.g. connecting/quering various databases without need to rewrite the entire code. This has nothing to do about query itself.

You can look at PDO extension, I usually use it together with prepared statements.
It will let you write queries like this:

```
$prepare = $db->prepare('
    SELECT 
      *
    FROM
      articles
    WHERE
      from=:from AND afield=:afield
    ORDER BY
      views
');

$prepare->bindValue(':from', $_GET['from'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$prepare->bindValue(':afield', $_GET['afield'], PDO::PARAM_STR);

$prepare->execute();

return $prepare;
```

The good thing about it is that you don't need to protect this from sql injections as PDO makes it for you. Also, the query is cached and you can run it several times with different params.

Answer (score 0):

Very bad practice to use raw GET params in query directly, i.e. you shouldn't make constructions like

SELECT * FROM articles WHERE from=$_GET['from'] AND afield='key' ORDER BY VIEWS
but instead something like
if ($_GET['from'] == 'smt') $from = 'smt'

SELECT * FROM articles WHERE from='$from' AND afield='key' ORDER BY VIEWS

and so on

P.S. keyword is 'sql injection'

Answer (score 0):

You can build the query string as pieces depending on what you need:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `articles` WHERE 1 = 1";

$where = ''

if (isset($_GET['from'])) {
    $where .= " AND `from` = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['from']) . "'"
}

if (isset($_GET['anotherInput'])) {
    $where .= " AND `from` = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['anotherInput']) . "'"
}

if (isset($_GET['sortby'] == 'views') {
    $orderby = " ORDER BY `views` DESC"
} else {
    $orderby = " ORDER BY `id` DESC"
}

$query = $query . $where . $orderby;

$result = mysql_query($query);
```

This is sort of the straight PHP/MySQL way, but I actually do suggest that you use prepared statements as in Pavel Dubinin's answer.

Answer (score -1):

This has nothing to do with patterns. Use the `$_GET` superglobal variable to dynamically generate your query string.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM articles WHERE from='".
         $_GET['from'].
         "' AND afield='".
         $_GET['anotherInput'].
         "' ORDER BY ".
         $_GET['sortby'];
```

**Disclaimer:** This is prone to SQL injection. Use input escaping and prepared statements, ex PDO, in a production environment like:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM articles WHERE from='?' AND afield='?' ORDER BY ?";
$clean_from = htmlentities($_POST['from'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
$clean_anotherInput = htmlentities($_POST['anotherInput'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
$clean_sortby = htmlentities($_POST['sortby'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
$clean_inputs = array($clean_from, $clean_anotherInput, $clean_sortby);

$sth = $dbh->prepare($query);
$sth->execute($clean_inputs);
```

Comment: I know about using $_GET, not here is the problem. But I don't know how can I generate the query depends by these inputs. For example, if sortby=views, I need to order the articles by views, else I need to order them by ID and the example can continue.

Comment: Be careful though - this code is prone to SQL Injection. Anything read in from $_GET is to be considered unsafe, and passing something with single quotes in this case would break this query.

Comment: But don't, for God's sake, put the $_GET directly into a database query! Unless of course you like SQL injection...?

Comment: @Matt @joksnet @Stephen Orr Yes it could be injected. I would use prepared statements and PDO, but this is just to demonstrate basic query creation.

Comment: Thanks you, I will validate all of these inputs before I using.